# AJAX Page Loader navigation bar

Tags: ajax

My site is:

http://econrespuestas.com.ar

And i'm having trouble with AJAX page loader integration. When you click on a link in "secondary-menu", it adds it the "current-menu-item" class, but it doesn't remove de "current-menu-item" class from the other ones.

I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
// highlight the current menu item
jQuery('secondary-menu li').each(function() {
    jQuery('thiss').removeClass('current-menu-item');
});
jQuery(thiss).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

but it isn't working. There must be something wrong with the removeClass selector. Could you help me?

Comment: `jQuery('thiss')` is probably not matching any elements, unless you have some `<thiss />` tags, which would be odd. Maybe you should refresh your knowledge of jQuery selectors and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `thiss` doesn't exist (unless declared somewhere else). It must be `this`. In addition try something more like...

```
jQuery('.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

This is saying "Remove the class `current-menu-item` from any objects with the class `current-menu-item`, then add the class `current-menu-item` to the parent `li` of the clicked item"

In addition, make sure that in your CSS, `.current-menu-item{...}` appears after any styling for the non-currently selected item.

---

### See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hR9K/2/

---

Also, unless you have a specific conflict with using the `$` sign in place of `jQuery`, I suggest doing exactly that.

```
$('.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
$(this).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Comment: thanks! I'm using "thiss" instead of "this" because I've defined the clicked element like that. However, your function isn't working. If I put that code instead of mine, I can't click on anything on the web

Comment: ok I have the solution!

    // highlight the current menu item
    jQuery('secondary-menu li').each(function() {
    
    });
    jQuery('.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    jQuery(thiss).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');

don't ask me why, this worked! Thanks!